# ag-grid material popup window

Tags: material-design

How to display popup in angular material 6 for ag-grid?

Comment: Hmm... So how should it be displayed? In what format?

Comment: ServiceInfo column has json content.I want to parse it and display either in the same row. or in popup

Comment: Has you tried use JSON.parse?, some like  `let obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');`

Comment: Hi all, Finally i am able to achieve what i have showed in above popup image. So, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `cellClicked` event that uses the interface `CellClickedEvent` which is triggered when the cell is clicked. That event can be listened to and data from the cell can be obtained. From there you could open a custom popup editor or a any popup and pass the data obtained from the event to the popup. That JSON data can be formatted and displayed in the popup.

Template will look like this-

```
<ag-grid-angular
     ...

     (cellClicked)="cellClicked($event)"

     ...
></ag-grid-angular>
```

In the component

```
public cellClicked(event: CellClickedEvent) {
  // Open popup here using the data
  alert(JSON.parse(event.data));
}
```

The events are given in the documentation here - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#selection

To display it in the same row, you could use a custom cell renderer to parse the JSON value and return a readable string. Read about cell renderers here - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#cell-renderer

Comment: alert is just a placeholder. You must write the code there to open your custom popup passing the JSON data to the popup. Implementing a custom popup is out of the scope of the answer. You can use [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog) or [MatDialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) to implement custom popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom cell template using ag-grid's [Cell Renderer Components](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#angular-cell-render-components). There are a few examples you can refer to over there as well.

First, you create a custom component that will allow you to display the JSON data. We a

```
import {ICellRendererAngularComp} from "ag-grid-angular";

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-cell',
  template: `
    <button (click)="clicked($event)"></button>
  `
})
export class CustomCellComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  private params: any;
  public cell: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
    console.log(params.value)
  }

  public clicked(cell: any): void {
    // show json data
    // open modal or popout
  }

  refresh(): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}
```

On your component that contains the main ag-grid, you will need to import the above `CustomCellComponent`,

```
import { CustomCellComponent } from "./custom-cell.component";
```

And on your column definitions, assign the custom component to the `cellRendererFramework` property.

```
{
  headerName: "Services Info",
  field: "servicesInfo",
  cellRendererFramework: CustomCellComponent,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cellRenderer in columnDefs object property to create/Render Custom cell.

you will get the Service Info column Object from **render.data.servicesInfo** .

Then get the specific data from Object and set the specific data in html template.

```
export class ClientsStatusComponent implements OnInit {
            columnDefs = [
                {headerName: 'Site Id', field: 'siteId' },
                {headerName: 'Customer Name', field: 'customerName' },
                {headerName: 'Customer Number', field: 'customerNumber'},
                {headerName: 'Database Name', field: 'databaseName' },
                {headerName: 'Server Name', field: 'serverName' },
                {headerName: 'Services Info', field: 'servicesInfo'},
                {headerName: 'Services Status', field: 'servicesInfo',cellRenderer: 
                 render => {
                   return `    
                     <span>`+render.data.servicesInfo.apiServicesHealth[0].serviceName+`</span> 
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     <span>`+render.data.servicesInfo.apiServicesHealth[0].serviceStatus+`</span>
                    `}
               }
            ];
            rowData: any;
            constructor(private http: HttpClient, private spinnerService: SpinnerService, private log: Log,
                private alertService: AlertService, private clientsStatusService: ClientsStatusService) {
            }

            ngOnInit() {
              this.loadClientStatus();
            }
                private loadClientStatus() {
                this.clientsStatusService.getClientsStatus().subscribe(
                    response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        debugger;
                        this.rowData = response.items;
                        return response;
                    },
                    errorRun => {
                        this.handleError('Error getting Applications.', errorRun)
                           // this.spinnerService.hide();
                    }
                );
            }
```